# Why do upper bounded braces in R grepl function find one more of the repeated token?

Tags: r, regex

From this [code golf post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183029/85522) with the relevant portion reproduced below.

> I also don't know why I need `{,2}` instead of `{,3}` but
>   it seems to work. If anyone knows the answer to that, let me know.
>
> ```
> grepl('^M{,2}(C[MD]|D?C{,2})(X[CL]|L?X{,2})(I[XV]|V?I{,2})$',scan(,''))
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCgIxEIThfp9DSAKpfIEUm2Yg2y4LIYLIcY2InKXx2WPurvu/YbYx1m15P727yTdef56r5NZz4l3BW@XSekl2EtW0dU04eHHx87i/fHQuhCHMZgYlljJDAVA@DBLBOUCNZs5BhPbXpGL8AQ)

For a simpler example:

```
rn <- c('X', 'MX', 'MMX', 'MMMX', 'MMMMX')
grepl('^M{,2}X$',rn)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Why does `{,2}` find 3 or fewer instances of `M` equivalent to `{0,3}`? Furthermore, why does this work at all? The regex guides I've found only speak of a missing upper bound (like `{3,}`) not a missing lower bound. If one has the `perl=TRUE` option set, R reads all as false.

```
> grepl('^M{,2}X$',rn, perl=T)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem  ...  The empty first instance quantification could be 0 (but see the link below to realize it's a slightly different issue) and as such it could match anything. Observe:

```
grepl('X{,2}', c("x","X","XX","XXX","XXXX") )
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Even the lower case-"x" gets a "pass" since it has no characters that match "X".

Turns out that this has been asked and answered before:

[Unexpected match of regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999964/unexpected-match-of-regex/47004617#47004617)

Comment: Question now edited with simpler example and better worded question.

Answer (score 1):

`{,n}` is not a commonly supported pattern for representing a quantity between `0` and `n` in regex. It works in Python, but most other regex flavors treat it as either a syntax error or character literals.

This is not to be confused with `{n,}` (between n and unlimited times) which is ubiquitous.

Instead, just use `{0,n}`.