# Is there a standard way to determine only maximum length?

Tags: regex

I have a case that I only care about the maximum number.
For instance, consider that I have to simply check that the string is: "max of 10 numeric digits", which means that it should meet the following:

- It contains only numbers (resolved).
- It has to be 10 digits at maximum.

I read about limiting the length, I came up with the following result:

- `^\d{10}$`: all numerics, 10 numbers specifically.
- `^\d{10,20}$`: all numerics, 10 - 20 length.
- `^\d{10,}$`: all numerics, 10 at minimum.

However, `^\d{,10}$` is invalid! Is there a specific way to do it, or should I do it as `^\d{1,10}$` ?

Comment: You can use; `^\d{0,10}$` as well

Comment: @anubhava `^\d{0,10}$` means that if there is no characters at all, it would be vaild. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct,. It will match an empty string as well. If you don't want that then `^\d{1,10}$`

Comment: @AhmadF the first number in the curly brackets is the lowest number of occurences of the element before the brackets. If you want between 1 and 10, use `^\d{1,10}$`

Comment: Some regex engines do actually support `^\d{,10}$`, such as python. Can you specify a language so that we can give more useful answers? Regex behaviour and syntax differ a lot from flavour to flavour.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, good to see you here :) Thanks for the tip. However, I think that I have to go with `^\\d{1,10}$`

Comment: @AhmadF In TRE, there [is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999964/unexpected-match-of-regex/47004617#47004617) with `^\d{,10}$`. What am I talking about, even `^.{273}$` [won't work in TRE](https://ideone.com/LMrCQu).

Answer (score 0):

`^\d{1,10}$` or [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s advice in the comment might simply suffice, yet there might be other excessive expressions such as:

```
^(?=[0-9]).{1,10}$
^(?=[0-9])\d{1,10}$
```

that might work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkqGIR/1/)